# The name 'Base' does not exist in the current context

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create a function to feed a log, I can't because I don't know how to pass the base parameter, I tried: Base, this, this.Base :)

Error : The name 'Base' does not exist in the current context

Thanks

```
    namespace ZLOG
    {
      public class INSERTLOG
      {
           public string exec(string traitement, string detail)
            {
              ZZLOGGRAPH graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ZZLOGGRAPH>();
              ZZLOG dac = new ZZLOG();
              dac.Logdate=DateTime.Now;
              PX.SM.Branch un_etab = PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>.Select(Base);  
              if (un_etab!=null) {dac.Logetab=un_etab.BranchCD;}
              
              graph.ListViewZZLOG.Insert(dac);
              graph.Actions.PressSave();
              return "OL";
            }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the ZZLOGGRAPH instance - graph.

```
PX.SM.Branch un_etab = PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>>>.Select(graph);
```